# VBScript To Process Array

Tags: vbscript, registry, wmi

I am attempting to add a few registry keys by using a VBScript.  For some reason the keys are not added, when I run this script.  I do not receive an error either.  Did I set up the array incorrectly?  The user has permissions to add/edit/modify the registry.

Code originally written by Daniel Pineault; all I did was add a `For Each` loop.

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

Dim oRegistry    
Dim sPath                   'Path to set as a Trusted Location    
Dim sDescription            'Description of the Trusted Location
Dim bAllowSubFolders        'Enable subFolders as Trusted Locations
Dim bAllowNetworkLocations  'Enable Network Locations as Trusted Locations
Dim bAlreadyExists
Dim sParentKey
Dim iLocCounter
Dim arrChildKeys
Dim sChildKey    
Dim sValue
Dim sNewKey

Set oRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
sPath = "C:\Test\"     
sDescription = "SetThroVBScript"
bAllowSubFolders = True
bAlreadyExists = False

x = Array("Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations","Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations","Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations","Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations")

For Each sParentKey In x
    iLocCounter = 0
    oRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sParentKey, arrChildKeys
    For Each sChildKey in arrChildKeys
        oRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sParentKey & "\" & sChildKey, "Description", sValue
        If sValue = sDescription Then bAlreadyExists = True

        If CInt(Mid(sChildKey, 9)) > iLocCounter Then
            iLocCounter = CInt(Mid(sChildKey, 9))
        End If
    Next

    If bAlreadyExists = False Then
        sNewKey = sParentKey & "\Location" & CStr(iLocCounter + 1)

        oRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sNewKey
        oRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sNewKey, "Path", sPath
        oRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sNewKey, "Description", sDescription

        If bAllowSubFolders Then
            oRegistry.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sNewKey, "AllowSubFolders", 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: WMI registry methods don't raise an error. You need to check their return code (`rc = oRegistry.CreateKey ... : WScript.Echo rc`). Presumably key creation fails because the parent key also doesn't exist. Keys aren't created recursively, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - thanks for the tip!  I was unaware of this.